# How can I set route with a specific subdomain in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am trying to set two different routes in rails, each linked to a different subdomain

This is something like I want do do

```
match "/"  => "first_app#index",
              as => :first_app_root, 
              :subdomain => 'application' 

match "/"  => "second_app#index",
              :as => :second_app_root,  
              :subdomain => 'another_application'
```

The result I want to get of course is `application.my_website` to point to the index action of the FirstAppController and the `another_application.my_website.dev` to point to the index action of the SecondAppController.

Also the `first_app_root_url` and `second_app_root_url` helper functions should create urls complete with the proper subdomains

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with match, you should be able to do it with the following statement.

```
match "/" => "first_app#index", :constraints => {:subdomain => "application"}
match "/" => "second_app#index", :constraints => {:subdomain => "another_application"}
```

but a cleaner way would probably be

```
constraints :subdomain => "application" do
  # add your routes normally
end

constraints :subdomain => "another_application" do
  # add your routes normally
end
```

Documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints

Comment: Event though this will make the routes innacessible if no proper domain is set, the helper functions generated by the `:as` setting do not have the proper subdomain prepended to them. I updated my question to reflect that

Comment: Can you try this ? first_app_root_url(:subdomain => request.subdomain) and second_app_root_url(:subdomain => request.subdomain) ?

Comment: This won't work if the link is displayed in a view of another controller. If I write my subdomain by hand it works though, so that's pretty close :)